# Pagination dots are not coming up in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

I was working on pagination , I see that there page control is not coming up for iOS 14 , where for iOS 13 and below is visible ..
Can some one please help me out on this

```
func designPageControl() {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.pageControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(didChangePage), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    self.pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX - 50, y: self.view.frame.maxY - 90, width: 100, height: 100)
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor =  UIColor(named: "GS-50")
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(named: "PB-100")
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried the view hierarchy inspector to see if the control is there but invisible/covered/something else?

Comment: I cannot see page control in view hierarchy , but I guess page control might have dropped down to some pixels in iOS 14 , but I don't know how much it has dropped

Answer (score 2):

Give the leading and trailing constraint to 20,20 and try.It worked for me. Dots size is increased in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (UIPageControl added programmatically was not showing up under iOS 14.x, but okay under prior iOS).

In Objective-C, adding:

```
 [pageControl sizeToFit];
```

before calling addSubView did the trick for me. In Swift, it would be:

```
pageControl.sizeToFit
```

Comment: add this *after* pageControl.numberOfPages = 4